# Why call ASP.NET WebAPI package libraries with version 5.1.0 as ASP.NET WebAPI 2.1?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-webpages

I want to get started with ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI that was released in Jan 2014.

ASP.NET MVC 5.1, ASP.NET Web API 2.1 and ASP.NET Web Pages 3.1 (Ref: NuGet)

I created a new ASP.NET Web application (.NET 4.5.1) > "Empty template" > "Web API" checked > "No Authentication"

Under the NuGet packages folder I checked the version of libraries referenced by this Web API empty project and found that all DLL (except NewtonSoft) is having a version similar to 5.1..

This is also true for ASP.NET MVC packages.

Question: All libraries are versioned as 5.1..., event ASP.NET MVC is called 5.1 then why is ASP.NET WebAPI called 2.1 - any specific reason or history behind it?

Comment: **Version 2.1 is the version you should pay attention to, since this is the version of ASP.NET Web API NuGet packages** and the only number used officially. The library version numbers 5.x are internal to the individual component libraries that make up Web API 2.1 - and 5.1 is no coincidence, as you've noticed, since Web API shares a common root with all the other web stuff. One way to think about it is as "ASP.NET Web API 2.1" being the *name* of the product, whereas 5.1 is the *internal version number* of the product - as with Windows 8 (the name) vs Windows 6.2 (the internal version).

Comment: @bzlm - thanks, Your response is more clear than Ofiris's answer, though he is not wrong, but this better explains in context of the question. I would appreciate if you can add your comment as proposed answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Version 2.1 is the version you should pay attention to**, since this is the named version of ASP.NET Web API NuGet packages and the only number used officially.

The library version numbers 5.x are internal to the individual component libraries that make up Web API 2.1 - and 5.1 is no coincidence, as you've noticed, since Web API shares a common root with all the other web stuff. So technically, ASP.NET Web API has two different versioning schemes, one being the official version of the product, and one being the library versions.

If you look at the NuGet package for ASP.NET Web API 2.2, you'll see that the URL is

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/5.2.0-rc

This means literally that this is ASP.NET Web API 2.2 version 5.2.0 RC, which is confusing. But one way to think about it is as "ASP.NET Web API 2.2" being the name of the product, whereas 5.2.0 is the internal version number of the product - as with Windows 8 (the name) vs Windows 6.2.9200 (the internal version).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that altough **ASP.NET MVC** and **ASP.NET Web API** are often used together in ASP.NET solutions, they are two different frameworks.

**ASP.NET Web API** is a newer product which was integrated into ASP.NET after `MVC`, and thus, the difference in the versioning.

Also not that `Razor` which is also a separate framework, is developed/released separately and   has its own versioning (3.0.0.0), some other libraries used under ASP.NET has different versions as well.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC or Razor. ASP.NET Web API *itself* has two different versioning schemes which the OP is asking about. Specifically, the [ASP.NET Web API 2.2 package has version 5.2 of all the libraries included](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/5.2.0-rc).

Comment: Good point, I agree, your answer answers better the question and should be the accepted answer.