# Asp.net Web.Api v2.2 is version 5.2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, version, asp.net-web-api2

What's the deal with the version numbering of Web.Api?   The releases are described as  "2.1", "2.2" but really map to package versions like "5.1.2" and "5.2.0".

For example, in [the v2.2 page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-22) we see "The latest ASP.NET Web API 2.2 package has the following version: "5.2.0" "

Call me confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***5.2*** is version of `ASP.NET MVC`.

***2.2*** is version of `ASP.NET Web API`.

Comment: I'm looking at my packages list (from NUGET) and I see items like "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.0.0" .  Not 2.2.  I don't see any packages with 2.2 on them.

Comment: I think this answer will explain it well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362315/why-call-asp-net-webapi-package-libraries-with-version-5-1-0-as-asp-net-webapi-2